# Help applying DDD to dynamic form application

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am designing an application that will display dynamically-generated forms to the user who will then enter values into the form fields and submit those values for persistence. The form represents an employee evaluation.

One use case allows an administrator (from HR) to define the form fields. They should be able to create a new form, add/remove fields from a form and mark a form as 'deleted'.

The second use case is when a manager views the form and enters values into the form fields for a specific employee.  They should be able to save the values at any time and recall the saved values when viewing the form again for the same employee.

Finally, when the manager is satisfied with the values they've entered for that employee, they can 'submit' the form data which persists the flattened data into the data warehouse for reporting purposes. When this is done, the 'working' copy of the data is removed so the form will display empty the next time they view it for that employee.

I am not concerned with the front-end at this point and working on the back-end service application that sits between the client and the data store.  The application must provide a course-grained interface for all of the behavior required.

My question is how many aggregate roots do I actually have (and from that, how many repositories, etc)?  Do I separate the form definition from the form data even though I need both when displaying the form to the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two main entities, 'EmployeeEvaluationSchema' and 'EmployeeEvaluation'. The 'EmployeeEvaluationSchema' entity would have a collection of 'FieldDefinition' value objects which would contain the properties that define a field, the most basic being the name of the field. The 'EmployeeEvaluation' entity would have a collection of 'FieldValue' value objects which contain the values for each field from the definition. In the simplest case, it would have a field name and value property. Next, the 'EmployeeEvaluation' could have a reference to 'EmployeeEvaluationSchema' to specify which definition the particular evaluation is based on. This can also be used to enforce the form definition in each evaluation. You would have two repositories - one for each entity. If you were to use an ORM such as NHibernate, then when you retrieve a 'EmployeeEvaluation' entity, the associated 'EmployeeEvaluationSchema' would also be retrieved even though there is a dedicated repository for it.

Comment: This is pretty much what I was initially thinking. To echo back, my service class would have a method like GetEmployeeEvaluation(empId) that calls the EmployeeEvaluationRepository.GetById(empId) method which is responsible for returning the entire EmployeeEvaluation aggregate root that includes the Schema as well as collection of Values.  When the service's SaveEmployeeEvaluation(eval) method is called, it calls the EmployeeEvaluationRepository.Update(eval) method which ignores the Schema and saves the Values. Am I on the same page?

Comment: Does it change your thinking at all if the schema and data (values) are stored in different databases?  (A new requirement.)

Comment: Where the data is stored is of less importance as long as your repositories can load the data. One consideration for an ORM is that if you have completely separate databases for each entity, you would have to use two repositories to load data, unless you are willing to have some de-normalization, so that the schema is replicated in the evaluation tables as well.

Answer (score 0):

From your description it sounds like your objects don't have any behavior and are simple DTOs. If that is the case maybe you should not bother doing DDD. Can you imagine your entities without having getters? There are better ways to do CRUDish application than DDD. Again this is only valid if your "domain" does not have relevant behavior.

Comment: You've hit on the one difficulty I've had grasping DDD - how much logic should be in the entity versus delegating/collaborating with 'services'.  For instance, in the case above, do I have a Submit() method on my entity or do I call SubmissionService.Submit(entity)? I lean towards the latter as I come from a component-oriented, BDD-type background and the submit process works with two entities (it takes the source "Evaluation" and creates a new "SubmittedEvaluation" that has a different model and persists it in the data warehouse using a different repository).

Comment: My rule of thumb is that the methods on my entities should be limited to manipulating the internal state of the entity but anything that requires interaction with external "components" are managed by a domain service. So the submission process would be managed by a SubmissionService which, as I said, creates the "SubmittedEvaluation" entity from the source, persists it to the data warehouse then uses the "EvaluationRepository" to remove the source "Evaluation". Given this approach, however, I find my domain objects do become very state-based with very little logic.

Comment: Is it me or you are describing an anemic domain model? Entities with mostly state and domain services doing the actual behavior. To me a big part of DDD is about boundaries. Aggregate boundaries and Context boundaries. Aggregates which tend to be self contained and don't depend on other components for their existence. I also tend to avoid introducing domain services without and explicit reason which usually is that the domain expert uses a therm which is neither an Entity or VO but a doer - a component that does a specific job and does not depend directly on other entities for that job.